# Problems with Threading in Python 2.5, KeyError: 51, Help debugging?

Tags: python, windows, multithreading

I have a python script which runs a particular script large number of times (for monte carlo purpose) and the way I have scripted it is that, I queue up the script the desired number of times it should be run then I spawn threads and each thread runs the script once and again when its done.

Once the script in a particular thread is finished, the output is written to a file by accessing a lock (so my guess was that only one thread accesses the lock at a given time). Once the lock is released by one thread, the next thread accesses it and adds its output to the previously written file and rewrites it.

I am not facing a problem when the number of iterations is small like 10 or 20 but when its large like 50 or 150, python returns a KeyError: 51 telling me element doesn't exist and the error it points out to is within the lock which puzzles me since only one thread should access the lock at once and I do not expect an error.

This is the class I use:

```
class errorclass(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.__queue=queue
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while 1:
              item = self.__queue.get()
              if item is None: break
              result = myfunction()
              lock = threading.RLock()
              lock.acquire()
              ADD entries from current thread to entries in file and
              REWRITE FILE
              lock.release()

queue = Queue.Queue()

for i in range(threads):
    errorclass(queue).start()

for i in range(desired iterations):
    queue.put(i)
for i in range(threads):
    queue.put(None)
```

Python returns with KeyError: 51 for large number of desired iterations during the adding/write file operation after lock access, I am wondering if this is the correct way to use the lock since every thread has a lock operation rather than every thread accessing a shared lock? What would be the way to rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

What you have right now is a *new lock* for every *iteration* in each thread's `run` method. In effect, there is no locking going on at all. If you want to protect writes to a file, you need to make sure that *all* threads that access the same file use the same lock object. The simplest way to do that is to create it at the global level:

```
lock = threading.RLock()
class errorclass(...):
    ...
    def run(self)
        ... # get items and process
        with lock:
            ADD entries from current thread to entries in file and REWRITE FILE
```

You'll need to use `from __future__ import with_statement` to use the `with` statement in Python 2.5, but it makes sure you never forget to unlock the lock, not even when an error occurs. (If you need Python 2.4-and-earlier compatibility, you'll have to use a try/finally instead.)

Answer (score 0):

Create the lock and pass it into `errorclass.__init__` so they do share an instance. Otherwise each thread is locking itself out of re-entering their own critical section which is exactly a no-op.